# Compile error on VS2013 when range-based for loop and do while loop are used simultaneously

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    for (int x : v) do {} while (0);
}
```

Compiling the code above on VS2013 will yield `error C2059: syntax error : '}'`. However, GCC can successfully compile the code.

To reproduce the error, the following requirements should be fulfilled:

1. Use range-based for loop;
2. Do not surround for-loop body by "{}";
3. Write a single "do while" statement in the for-loop body.

Any insight on this?

Comment: Is this the result of a macro expansion or how did you find that bug?

Comment: This is the result of some macro expansion like `do {blabla} while (0) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug, and it's fixed in VS2015.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parentheses to avoid MSVC 2013 error. The following code is compiling fine in MSVC 2013 Update 4:

```
std::vector<int> v;
for (int x : v)
{
    do
    {
    } while (0);
}
```